# Python - can't find tkinter

Tags: python

I'm using Linux 16.04, and few day ago- I got this error, regardless IDE i'm using.

Any Ideas why?

```
import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-tk package')
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package
```

Comment: Maybe becayse you don't have `tkinter` installed?

Comment: Have you tried installing the python3-tk package?

Comment: @Adelin it worked before

Comment: @J.Deere you might want to add such crucial information in the question itself.

Comment: @Adelin you are right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following -

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

`tkinter` cannot be installed via pip (as far as I know).

Comment: probably it disappeared in a way i can't understand. Reinstalling work Great!!